# How can I use Curl between 2 applications in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, curl

I have one project which is connected with DB. And another separate project which has no connection to DB.

Now I want to create an API in second project to store customer data. It will accept customer data in json along with access token. Now this data will be passed on to API of first project. It will read the json and store data in DB.

I am getting confused. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have a read of the [HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) Laravel provides for doing these things.

Comment: I would make this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#defining-schedules in first project which will get data from second project. Second project must have route to accept requests from 1st project and if it is POST, then not forget to add CsrfException(in 2nd pr.)